# How to force Moment.js to prioritize day before month when parsing ambiguous dates?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Is there a way to force Moment.js to always assume that the day comes before the month in ambiguous situations?

**For example:**

- `moment("10-05-2018")` should be 10 May 2018
- `moment("06/08/2018")` should be 06 August 2018
- `moment("01 03 2018")` should be 01 March 2018

Comment: Pass it a format string?

Comment: You can (and should) pass an explicit format string as the second argument. You could examine your dates and pick a format based on what you know about the nature of your data.

Comment: You've included examples of ambiguous situations, but not examples of unambiguous situations. The same code may not work for both.

Comment: @HereticMonkey—all 3 are ambiguous for some and depending on context, many.

Comment: `moment('10-05-2018', 'DD-MM-YYYY')`.

Comment: Ok I solved it by using the moment(String, String[]) method, where I pass an array of  formats that should be tried.

Comment: @RobG That's... kind of my point. If the OP wants something that will parse all of "10-05-2018", "10-31-2018", and "31-10-2018", the answer given would not help.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), where `DD` is day of month, `MM` is month number and `YYYY` is 4 or 2 digit year.

Please note that since your input is neither in a recognized ISO 8601 nor RFC 2822 format, you should use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) over [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) to get consistent results across browsers.

> When creating a moment from a string, we first check if the string matches known [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats, we then check if the string matches the [RFC 2822 Date time](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.3) format before dropping to the fall back of `new Date(string)` if a known format is not found.

**Warning:** Browser support for parsing strings is [inconsistent](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html). Because there is no specification on which formats should be supported, what works in some browsers will not work in other browsers.

> 

For consistent results parsing anything other than ISO 8601 strings, you should use [String + Format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Here a live sample

```js
["10-05-2018","06/08/2018", "01 03 2018"].forEach( (item) => {
  console.log( moment(item, 'DD MM YYYY').format() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ok I ended up solving it by using the moment(String, String[]) method, where I pass an array of  formats that should be tried first.